# Azure Active Directory JWT aud value

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

In JWT from AAD there is a key 'aud'. https://jwt.io/, says it is 'Audience. (Who or what the the token is intended for)'. My question is, *Are `aud` values website specific - can I check the aud and expect it to be same to check if the token is intended for my specific site?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure AD, the audience value always indicates the resource the token is targeted on.

You can acquire an access token by using either the API's client id or Application ID URI.
What you use will be the audience in the token.
So if you make an API, you should check the audience is either the API's client id or Application ID URI.
You can know for sure it will always be one of those if the token is meant for your API.

EDIT: The below information is not correct.
If I know your API's identifier + your tenant id,
I can acquire an access token for your API using client credentials!
The token will not contain scopes or roles, it cannot.
So it is critical that you check for the presence of valid delegated permissions (aka scopes) or valid app permissions (in roles claim).

> THIS IS WRONG: If I tried to acquire an access token using your API's identifier from my AAD tenant, it would not give me a token.
>   Any app that passes an access token with the correct audience had rights to call your API when it acquired the token.

Answer (score 1):

You already got a good explanation of the audience value from juunas.

I'm adding here a specific code example from Azure-Samples on Github which shows how to validate the JWT Token manually and checks among other things audience value. (It's pretty important to validate issuer as well)

Look at this particular code and especially near the comment "**We accept both the App Id URI and the AppId of this service application**"

```
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // We accept both the App Id URI and the AppId of this service application
                ValidAudiences = new[] { audience, clientId },

                // Supports both the Azure AD V1 and V2 endpoint
                ValidIssuers = new[] { issuer, $"{issuer}/v2.0" },
                IssuerSigningKeys = signingKeys
            };
```

Code Sample:

[**Specific file with code excerpt shown above**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs#L58)

[**Azure-Samples: Manually validating a JWT access token in a web API**](http://Manually%20validating%20a%20JWT%20access%20token%20in%20a%20web%20API)